# Core Graphics raster data not releasing from memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, core-graphics

So I'm getting my App to take a screen shot and save it to the photo album with the code below...

```
- (void) save {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0 );
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage,nil,NULL,NULL);
        NSData*theImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1.0 );
        [theImageData writeToFile:@"image.jpeg" atomically:YES];
    }
```

How can I release the memory allocated by Core Graphics that is holding the screenshot raster data?

My project is using ARC for memory management. When testing how the App is allocating memory I've noticed that memory is not being released after taking the screen shot, causing the app to grow sluggish over time. The 'Allocation Summary' in Instruments is telling me that the data category is 'CG raster data' and the responsible caller is 'CGDataProviderCreatWithCopyOfData'.

Is there a solution in CFRelease(); ?

My first App so I'm pretty noob, I've had a look around the internet to try and resolve the issue with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the contents of your method into an `@autorelease` block.

```
@autoreleasepool {
...
}
```

Comment: do you mean @autoreleasepool?

Comment: Indeed, sorry for that.

Comment: It worked for me. No need to down vote. Maybe you did not autorelease the right block.

Comment: You have lot's of answers that I've upvoted also, this just not one of them.